# Is there a link between animal names which are their own plurals and domesticability?

Tags: etymology, nouns, grammatical-number, history

Moose, caribou, bear, ibex, zebra, buffalo, deer. All are their own plurals, although 'bears' is far more common. None are domesticable. Sheep would seem to be an exception. To what degree is this coincidence?

Comment: I think you will find that StoneyB has answered your question. These things are left invariant in a hunting context. Many but certainly not all have normal count-noun plurals otherwise, like lions and tigers and bears and foxes and zebras, but not moose or elk or caribou or sheep or fish or deer. However, I will note that reindeer are domesticated, and tropical fish are too. :)

Comment: @tchrist Wikipedia says "The reindeer is the only domesticated deer in the world and was the last animal to be domesticated, though it may be more accurate to consider reindeer as semi-domesticated." Otherwise, yep, StoneyB seems to have it there.